# How do I obtain my Drupal (or TYPO3 or Backdrop or WordPress) database credentials using DDEV?

Tags: ddev

I just finished spinning up a DDEV Drupal 8 instance using the quickstart guide, and I want to go through the install process, but Drupal needs database credentials, of course. I can't seem to find them anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

The db credentials are super easy, and easy to obtain, `ddev describe`. They're also easy to remember: Username=db, Password=db, Database=db, Hostname=db. When doing an install on Drupal though the hostname field is hidden in the "advanced" fieldset, and it defaults to "localhost" so things won't work if you don't open that fieldset and set it.

Also, your very reasonable [issue](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/776) suggests outputting these creds on site start.

One more item: When you do a `ddev config` ddev *tries* to create a settings file (settings.local.php or settings.php on Drupal, AdditionalConfiguration.php on TYPO3, etc. It can't always do that because you might already have those files, and ddev will never alter your settings files. But when it does, it includes those credentials. On *Drupal* though that means that the normal install.php redirect doesn't work as expected (because the db credentials already exist). So on a Drupal site you'll need to hit install.php on a fresh site that hasn't had a database imported. For example. http://mysite.ddev.local/install.php.